# ¿Cómo importar datos desde Archivo excel a SQL Server con autoincrement?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, importación, datos

tengo un archivo excel con la siguiente estructura:

| ID | NOMBRE | APELLIDO | RUT | DV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | JUAN | LASTNAME | 18XXXXXX | 2 |

El archivo tiene 768 filas, actualmente importo el documento con la herramienta de importación de SQL Server y el driver corresponddiente. Mi problema es que el ID no tiene datos porque quiero que sea autoincrementable. Pero al agregarlo me queda null o simplemente me tira error cuando edito la consulta SQL que generá.

No sé como poder hacer esto, primera vez que me enfrento a esta problematica.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Muestra los datos de la estructura de tu tabla y demás características para reproducir tu escenario. Saludos

Comment: Si quieres usar un identity para el ID, simplemente no debes importar esta columna y dejar que sea el motor el que la genere.